# What motivation is there to create general, cross-species neural models which account for the variation between species in different environments?

Tags: neuroscience, ecology, systems-biology

The main components of human neuroanatomy have been mapped out. What attempt has there been to map a *broad* (many-species) spectrum of functional parts of the nervous system? Such a mapping could be useful in behavioral ecology, which associates functional behaviors with driving environmental forces.